# How to scrollTo an element in a pop-up window - Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, xpath, popup, testcafe

I have a scenario, where we have to accept the terms and conditions before registering  to an account. There is a small check box on left side to accept the terms and condtions and also there is an hyperlink, where user can read the terms and condtions.

Problem - When I click on the hyperlink, a pop-up appears  and i'm not able to close this pop-up window.

CSS-Selectors used:

```
this.acceptpolicy               = Selector('[class*="terms-and-conditions_policyTextContainer__2xgGL"] [class*="checkbox_container"] label');
this.closemodelbtn              = Selector('[class*="modal_close"]');
```

Code snippet written in TestCafe, nodeJS:

```
await t.click(this.acceptpolicy)
await window.scrollBy(-500,0)
await t.click(this.closemodelbtn)
```

When I use the above window.scrollBy(), it tries to scroll the background screen and not the pop-up window screen. I am trying to scroll to right and click on the cross mark.
Attaching screenshot of the pop-up window with element inspection.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [TestCafe's scrollBy method](https://testcafe.io/documentation/403066/reference/test-api/testcontroller/scrollby) that was introduced in v1.14:

```
await t.scrollBy(this.acceptpolicy, -500, 0)
```

Don't forget to update TestCafe if you are using an earlier version.

Comment: thanks for ur inputs. Is there a way where user can just enter ESC button and the pop-up disappears?

Comment: If you want to emulate the Esc key press, use the corresponding [pressKey](https://testcafe.io/documentation/402693/reference/test-api/testcontroller/presskey) method. If you wish your dialog to be closed with the Esc key, make sure that it supports this behavior.